# PHP allow user to only view file after form submission

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess

I have a basic file. The user can only view the file after a successfull form submission.

Now I know I have a variety of options I could use including placing it in a dir and modifying my `.htaccess` and then use a parameter which I pass through a routing script to let the user view the file as pointed out by numerous answers to somewhat similar questions. (which would probably be best option)

*However Im just curious* about something. "*How Secure*" would the following be.

Both files reside in a directory called xyz
`Directory public_html/xyz`

**Form.php**

`<form method ="post" action="displayInfo.php" />`

**displayInfo.php**

Now what I would like to know is IF i set the following code at the start of `displayInfo.php` would it stop with unauthorized access (i.e. prevent user from viewing the file IF he / she did not successfully submit the form)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'){
    die("first submit the form")
}
```

Comment: I'd place the file outside the public area and simply include that file. Folders and files inside the public area are guessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wouldn't. I could defeat your security precaution with a simple cURL command:

`curl -X POST https://example.com/displayInfo.php`

The check for a POST request will pass, because it indeed a post request. However, it has absolutely none of the data you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you suggest...? Put the files `displayInfo.php` in a different directory and modify `.htaccess`?

Comment: It depends on your intent. Why are you doing this? If it's an anti-hotlinking measure, you don't really need any security beyond what you showed.
If you are collecting data, check the each submitted field if it contains something.